# How to implement many similar methods for trait?

Tags: generics, rust, serde

I am implementing  the [Serde `Serializer` trait](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/ser/trait.Serializer.html) which has a lot of methods. Many of them look quite similar (for example those for integer types just copy bytes to some buffer), so it would be nice to generate them somehow. Can I write some generic function or macro to implement many of them with one method (macro)?

I have something like this:

```
use serde::Serializer;
use byteorder::{WriteBytesExt, LittleEndian};

struct MySerializer {
     ...
}

impl Serializer for MySerializer {
    fn serialize_i32(&mut self, v:i32) -> Result<(), Error> {
        try!(self.buffer.write_i32::<LittleEndian>(v));
    }
    fn serialize_u8(&mut self, v:u8) -> Result<(), Error> {
        try!(self.buffer.write_u8::<LittleEndian>(v));
    }
    // many similar looking functions here
}
```

Comment: Rust _does_ support generic programming: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/generics.html

Comment: @gbe Sure, I know it does. However I need not just generics, I need to generate new functions with new identifiers (names). My current understanding is that it's unfortunatelly impossible now, because rust's macro rules do not allow generating new idents..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and example in [serde/bench](https://github.com/serde-rs/bench/blob/master/src/de.rs) project:

```
macro_rules! impl_nums {
    ($ty:ty, $dser_method:ident, $visitor_method:ident, $reader_method:ident) => {
        #[inline]
        fn $dser_method<V>(&mut self, mut visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value>
            where V: Visitor
        {
            let value = try!(self.reader.$reader_method::<NativeEndian>());
            visitor.$visitor_method(value)
        }
    };
}

impl_nums!(u16, deserialize_u16, visit_u16, read_u16);
impl_nums!(u32, deserialize_u32, visit_u32, read_u32);
....
```

It looks like for now it is the best possible way to do it -  [`concat_idents!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat_idents.html) macro is unstable, and is not very useful acording to [this github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/13294).